# Residence permit card in Finland sent while travelling back to U.K

Tags: visas, residency, finland, brexit

I have been granted a residence right in Finland based on the EU-UK Withdrawal Agreement. My card, however, will be posted in January 2021 to my address in Finland. As Christmas is coming up, it would be nice to go back to U.K. this year for a short while and come back to Finland in January 2021. I have a document saying the residence has been granted but would border control in Finland need to see the official residence permit card on my return in 2021? (I will not have it on my return journey and will only receive the official card when I come back sometime in January)

Comment: Do note that casual international trips "for a short while" are unlikely to be practicable or safe this year due to the covid-19 situation.

Comment: I'd recommend you to email Finnish border control about this. Would you be travelling to/from Helsinki airport?

Comment: @Crazydre Thanks for your advice. Yes it would be to and from Helsinki airport. Do you know what is the correct email address for the Finnish border control?

Comment: @CAF For Helsinki airport it's hkv@raja.fi. Attach the approval letter.